# For any unitary in the bicommutant, there exists a net of unitaries converging to that unitary in the strong operator topology.

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

I am trying to make an excercise given during lectures on operator algebras.

> Let $A\subset\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ be a concrete (subset of operators on a Hilbert space) unital C*-algebra. Let $M=A''$ the bicommutant of $A$. Show that for every unitary $u$ in $M$, there exists a net of unitaries $v_\lambda\in A$ such that $v_\lambda\to u$ in the strong operator topology.

There is the extra hint that you should remember that $e^{it}=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

What I tried so far is the following.

First of all note that $M$ is a von Neumann algebra, as a consequence of the bicommutant theorem. For this we can show that every unitary is of the form $\exp(ih)$ for some $h\in M$ self-adjoint and $\lvert\lvert h\rvert\rvert\leq \pi$, using the Borel functional calculus. We also have by the Kaplinsky density theorem that the ball of radius $\pi$ of self-adjoints in $A$ lies dense inside the ball of radios $\pi$ of self-adjoints in $M$.  We can therefore find a net $h_\lambda\in A$ of self-adjoints with radius at most $\pi$. Using continuous functional calculus we can define $\exp(ih_\lambda)$ and it is not hard to see these are unitaries.

To conclude I would need to show that for all $\xi\in\mathcal{H}$, we have $$\lvert\lvert(\exp(ih)-\exp(ih_\lambda))(\xi)\rvert\rvert\to 0$$ but I do not really know how I can say anything about this norm. Does anyone know how to proceed and if this is the right approach?

Comment: If you already know Kaplansky's density theorem, do you also know that functional calculus is strongly continuous on norm bounded sets? This is usually used in the course of the proof of Kaplansky's density theorem.

Comment: Ah yes, this escaped me for a moment. I got it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is strongly continuous, if for every Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and net of self-adjoints $\alpha_\lambda\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ with $\alpha_\lambda\to \alpha$ in the SOT, we have that $f(\alpha_\lambda)\to f(\alpha)$ in the SOT.

It is sufficient to show that $\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}\exp(it)/t=0$ in order for $t\mapsto exp(it)$ to be strongly continuous. This clearly holds.

Since $h_\lambda$ is a net of self-adjoints converging to $h$ in the operator topology, it converges to $h$ in the strong operator topology. Hence, the result follows by applying the definition of the $f$ being strongly continuous.